# Can FAXCOMEXLib and Windows Fax Service send a color fax?

Tags: c#, colors, fax

We are in the process of testing different options for sending faxes from within our C# code (receiving faxes is not necessary).  One of those options is to use FAXCOMEXLib.

Without surprise, I've had pretty good success sending out black & white faxes with FAXCOMExLib.  But we also have a requirement to support sending color faxes.  So I execute the following code (just a snippet):

```
IFaxDocument oFaxDoc = new FaxDocumentClass();
oFaxDoc.Body = @"C:\Test\color_image.jpg";
oFaxDoc.ConnectedSubmit(m_oFaxServer);
```

The image is 24bit color, 1728x2304, 204x196 dpi.

For the most part, this process works (with a couple of small quirks) and the fax shows up in my "Windows Fax and Scan" outbox (I'm on Vista).  The problem is the image has been dithered to a 1bit black & white image.  I assume that what I see in "Windows Fax and Scan" is what is actually transmitted.

So is there a way to send a color fax using this technology?  Are we missing a configuration option somewhere to make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally got an answer elsewhere.  Windows Fax Service does not support color faxes.

Comment: 5 years later, wonder if they do now.  But I'm having trouble testing by sending a color fax from an internet account efax.  So I suspect they all don't for the low end services.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using this program to transmit faxes for a year and it does not support color fax transmissions.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16555956)

Comment: @Martin. The poster is saying that color faxes are not supported. Which I think is a legitimate answer to the question.